# Replace each string in array with different object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "children": [
            "5efa29058a3e8a3efc45c11a",
            "5efa29158a3e8a3efc45c11b"
        ],
        "_id": "5efa29b88a3e8a3efc45c11f",
        "tabText": "foo",
        "headerText": "foobar",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "children": [
            "5efa29228a3e8a3efc45c11c",
            "5efa292c8a3e8a3efc45c11d",
            "5efa29338a3e8a3efc45c11e"
        ],
        "_id": "5efa29ea8a3e8a3efc45c120",
        "tabText": "Foo2",
        "headerText": "foobar2",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

For each "children" array on each object I need to take the childs id, look it up in the database, and replace the id string with an object containing the info from the database.

Mongoose Models:

Model1:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')

const Tab = model('tab', new Schema({
  tabText: String,
  headerText: String,
  children: Array
}))

module.exports = Tab
```

Model2:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')

const Child = model('child', new Schema({
  icon: String,
  name: String,
  description: String
}))

module.exports = Child
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: why not give a try by using one for-loop or one forEach?

Comment: Looks like you are using MongoDB. You can populate those id's with the actual documents in your backend. You don't have loop through the docs and then send multiple requests to populate each of them.

Comment: @RameshReddy How do I do that? I know how to join tables in SQL but not in mongo, i did't know it was possible.

Comment: @LoganB Are you using mongoose?

Comment: @RameshReddy Yes using mongoose. These are two seperate models. When i call Model1.find() I get the array in the question, the children are ID's from Model2

Comment: @LoganB - Update the question with the models.

Comment: @RameshReddy Updated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The models should be defined like this to form a relationship.

**Model1:**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')

const Tab = model('Tab', new Schema({
  tabText: String,
  headerText: String,
  children: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child' }],
}))

module.exports = Tab
```

**Model2:**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')
const Child = model('Child', new Schema({
  icon: String,
  name: String,
  description: String
}))
module.exports = Child
```

Now the `children` will reference the ids of `Child` documents.

And when you want to populate them you can use:

```
await Tab.findOne().populate('children')
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works perfectly! And I learned something new today that will help immensely in the future. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to map over the array twice:

```
// First: map over each element in the array.
const newArray = array.map(arrElement => {
    // Now arrElement is just one of our array elements.

    // Then we can map over each element of the arrElement.children
    // to get each id separately.
    return arrElement.children.map(id => {
        // Do stuff with the id...
        // Make sure to return your new object from this function.
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a good case for `Promise.all` so you can run the queries in parallel

```js
await Promise.all(
  input.map(async (item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      children: await Promise.all(
        item.children.map(async (childId) => {
          return await getItemFromDatabase(childId);
        })
      ),
    };
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace each string in a Array. Here is a standard way of doing this.

'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map'

`const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];`

// pass a function to map

`const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);`

`console.log(map1);`

// expected output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32]